# How to overcome vuex "state property is read only" within a store mutation?

Tags: vuex

I have a vuex action that commits to a mutation:

```
updateStateProperty: (state, payload) => {
  state.parent.child = payload.changer
}
```

This throws out a:

> TypeError: ""child" is read-only"

I've seen this example solution, but it's missing explanation for deepClone purpose:

```
[types.SET_FIELD] (state, payload) {
  let parent = deepClone(state.parent)
  parent.child = payload.changer

  state.parent = parent
}
```

Also seen other stuff but no clear code example.
How should I go about changing this property?